# C++ templated ofstream characters printing in decimal

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am making a generic logger class which I prints anything passed into a file.

```
Logger::Instance()->write('c');
Logger::Instance()->write("this");
Logger::Instance()->write(5);
```

However I run into an issue where I have:

```
char c = 't';
Logger::Instance()->write(c);
```

Which prints decimal instead of the ascii:

```
116
```

Strings work fine but characters are the only thing having issues.

My code:

```
class Logger {
public:
    static Logger* Instance();
    bool open(string filename);
    template<typename T>
    void write(T data) {
        file << data;
    }
    bool close();
```

If I make a char specific printing function:

```
void write(char data) {
    file << data;
```

It will print the character. Not sure what is going on here.

**Edit 1:**

Just a summary.. So why does this print the numerical:

```
void write(T data) {
    file << data;
}
```

And this print the correct ascii:

```
void writeChar(char data) {
    file << data;
}
```

???

**Edit 2:**

Here is my code:

[logger.h](http://pastebin.com/fzqE6SJq)
[logger.cpp](http://pastebin.com/KgjyAqj8)

Use this class and just go:

```
char c = 't';
Logger::Instance()->write(t);
Logger::Instance()->writeChar(t);
```

**Edit 3:**

Alright.. here is the last source file.

```
[keyboardhook.cpp][3]
[keyboardhook.h][4]
[main.cpp][5]

[3]: http://pastebin.com/VEav4kfn
[4]: http://pastebin.com/yPwF17yg
[5]: http://pastebin.com/JwHz2NBe
```

Take a look here:

```
if(isdigit(c)) {
        Logger::Instance()->write((char) c);
        Logger::Instance()->writeChar(c);
    } else if(isalpha(c)) {
        if(!shift)
            Logger::Instance()->writeChar(tolower((char) c));
        else
            Logger::Instance()->writeChar((char) c);
```

Stackoverflow keeps flagging my writing as 'code' and is giving me problems when saving.. sorry for the wait.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c15c897711a932bc) print?

Comment: You should post an SSCCE (see sscce.org). I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @user2997491, about your "Edit 2" - it writes 'tt' into the file. Maybe you have set some flags of the output stream that causes this behavior?

Comment: In a function I get process_key(int keyDecimalVal). So I cast it to a char before printing it: char c = (char) keyDecimalVal;. But visual studio says it was converted correctly with debugging... hm..

Comment: @user2997491, here you have an online compiler http://ideone.com/ . Try to paste only necessary parts of your code, check if it works and paste a link to the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked fine in Visual C++ 2010 (as I would expect):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Logger {
    template <typename T>
    void write(T data) {
        std::cout << data;
    }
};

int main() {
    Logger *log = new Logger;
    char c = 't';
    log->write(c);
    delete log;
}
```

Perhaps you have some custom-defined `operator<<`'s that are causing this behavior for you? Could you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

**Edit:**

For future reference, here is what would have constituted a SSCCE for your problem (based on your complete code):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Logger {
template <typename T>
    void write(T data) {
        std::cout << data;
    }
};

int main() {
    Logger *log = new Logger;
    char c = 't';
    log->write(tolower(c));
    delete log;
}
```

The key problem is that the signature of tolower is `int tolower(int c)`, that is, it returns an integer, not a character. As such, `write<int>` is called, rather than `write<char>`.

Please keep in mind how important an sscce is! Your question didn't include the very important bit of code that caused the problem.

Comment: @user2997491 I assume you mean Edit #1? There is something going on in code that you have not posted. Please create a sscce, we really won't be able to help you otherwise, and the process of creating the sscce may show you the problem on its own.

Comment: @user2997491 Again, not a sscce. Even after adding `Logger::Instance()->open("test.txt");`, text.txt still contains "tt" as expected.